# Excel if then formula, 3 variables, 1 output

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to make it so that on this sheet, if the value in e2 matches b2, c2, or d2, F2 will display the corresponding column header name. I can get it to work in a single statement, but once i try to get all 3 in there it fails to display the column names up top as the correct one to purchase from.

In easy terms, whichever price shows up in e2 that is the lowest, f2 will display the vendor to buy from. I already figured out my min statement, but need to figure out how to get it to display the column header.[Excel spreadsheet screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/top50.png)

In the screenshot, f2 should say `sysco`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have minimum price already calculated in `E2` you can use:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH($E2,$B2:$D2,0))
```

Without `E2` you can also calculate it in one formula:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$D$1,MATCH(MIN($B2:$D2),$B2:$D2,0))
```

This is for all versions of Excel.
In new versions you can also use `XLOOKUP` function:

```
=XLOOKUP(MIN($B2:$D2),$B2:$D2,$B$1:$D$1)
```